# Building as lib makes debug configuration much slower

Tags: c++, visual-studio, performance, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have a project in VS2017 professional, version 15.9.7.
The project builds output is program.exe.

I've renamed it and changed it to create a static library program.lib. I've kept the configuration of the program.lib as much similar to that of program.exe I was creating before.
Here we have the configuration flags of the old program.exe and of the new program.lib (please ignore the paths that I've just created at hand):

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /MP /GS- /W4 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"...my includes" /Zi /Gm- /Od /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:fast /D "USE_EIGEN" /D "EIGEN_FAST_MATH" /D "EIGEN_NO_AUTOMATIC_RESIZING" /D "VISUALSTUDIO=100" /D "_DEBUG" /D "WIN64" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /arch:AVX /Gd /MTd
/openmp /std:c++17 /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHa /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\program.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

These are the flags for the linker:

```
/OUT:"program.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"program.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "program.lib" "....my libs" /STACK:"32768"",32768" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"program.pgd"/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"program.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"...my libpaths" /TLBID:1
```

Then I've used that library just to create a new exe program1.exe. I've kept the same configuration flags as before.

Everything works fine and the speed of program1.exe built in release is the same than that of program.exe, but if I run the new program1.exe in debug from visual studio it is much much slower, so that it is not usable any more. Thus in this case speed in debug is important.

The speed in release is kept the same.

Why?

Any ideas to make it faster?

Comment: please provide a [mre]. Does debug speed really matter? Is the release speed also slower?

Comment: Did you create a new exe project and then reference the static library program and find that it is much slower under debug? Could you please provide a small sample with us?

Comment: What is your VS2017 version, enterprise or professional?

Answer (score 0):

> Everything works fine, but if I run the new program1.exe in debug from
> visual studio it is much much slower.

It is quite strange and you could try the following steps to troubleshoot your issue:

**1)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of the two projects.

**2)** make sure that the two projects use the same platform and configuration like `X64/Debug`.

**3)** click **Empty Symbol Cache** option under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Debugging**-->**Symbols** and also click `Load only specified modules`.

And try to uncheck `Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging` under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Debugging**-->**General**.

**4)** disable any third party extensions under **Tools**-->**Extensions and Updates** in case some extensions cause this behavior.

**5)** reset all vs settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset All Settings** to check whether some obscure extra settings cause the issue. And you can also make a backup before you do it.

**In addition**, if your **VS2017** is **Enterprise**, please uncheck the option `Enable IntelliTrace` under `Tools` --> `Options` --> `IntelliTrace`